# Java Arrays - Searching an element in an array and then find the index

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program for searching a city, given a postal code. The program has to search that postal code in the array postalcode and give the name of the city back.
The code I have so far is:

.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Postalcode 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] postalcode = {9300,2000,1000,9200,9000,8500,9700,2300};
        String[] city = {"Aalst","Antwerpen","Brussel","Dendermonde","Gent","Kortrijk","Oudenaarde","Turnhout"};

        int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a postal code")); 
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to link the code that's been asked to a city in the array. For exemple, the user types as code 2000, so that's postalcode[1], the city I want is Antwerpen because city[1].

Comment: You would be *far* better served with a `Map<Integer, String>`.

Comment: are you open for alternatives other than arrays? in your case, a map will be good data structure on your given scenario

Comment: I haven't worked with maps before, I am trying to improve my knowledge of arrays in java. So I want to do this program with arrays

Comment: Use the correct data structure for the problem at hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a postal code"));

int requiredIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < postalcode.length; i++)
    if (postalcode[i] == code)
        requiredIndex = i;
if (requiredIndex == -1){
    //there is no such postal code
} else {
    //your city is
    System.out.println(city[requiredIndex]);
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. It isn't that difficult, I should be able to have figured it out myself dough.

Answer (score 4):

I would seriously consider using a HashMap for this instead of 2 Arrays.

```
HashMap<int,String> cities =  new HashMap<int,String>();
cities.put(9000,"Gent");
cities.put(9400,"Aalst"); 
String city = cities.get(9400);
System.out.println(city);
```

To further adapt to your assignment:

```
 int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a postal code"));
 string city = cities.get(code);
```

EDIT: Solution for Arrays:

This is a very weird approach I must say but if you really want to do it with arrays:

I'm assuming that the length of the city array is the same as the length of the postalcode array.

```
   int index = 0;
   int pCode = 9300;

for (int i = 0; i < postalcode.length; i ++)
{                       
  if (pCode == postalcode[i])
     {
        index = i;
        break;
     }

 }   

System.out.println(cities[index])
```

Comment: I don't want to work with maps, I want to improve my knowledge of arrays. So this will be a challenge for me without you.

Comment: @user1873613 : its upto you what you want to use or learn. As for the answer it doesn't deserve a downvote

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the accepted answer will take linear time per query. While a `HashMap` is still a better option (with constant amortized time), you can do better than linear time with arrays if you rearrange them so that `postalCode` is sorted. This allow you to perform `O(log(n))` binary searches.

**Example:**

```
final int[] orderedPostCode = { 1000, 2000, 2300, 8500, 9000, 9200, 9300, 9700 };
final String[] orderedCities = { "Brussel", "Antwerpen", "Turnhout", "Kortrijk", "Gent", "Dendermonde", "Aalst", "Oudenaarde" };

final int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a postal code"));

final int codePos = Arrays.binarySearch(orderedPostCode, code);
if (codePos < 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Postal code not found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "City: " + orderedCities[codePos]);
}
```

---

This leads to a interesting follow up problem: How to sort an arbitrary set of postal codes and cities in the way needed for fast binary searches:

```
int[] postalCode = {9300,2000,1000,9200,9000,8500,9700,2300};
String[] city = {"Aalst","Antwerpen","Brussel","Dendermonde","Gent","Kortrijk","Oudenaarde","Turnhout"};

int[] orderedPostCode = Arrays.copyOf(postalCode, postalCode.length);
Arrays.sort(orderedPostCode);
String[] orderedCities = rearrangeCities(city, postalCode, orderedPostCode);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orderedPostCode));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orderedCities));
// Will print the arrays of the first example
```

And here is the `rearrangeCities` implementation `O(n²)`:

```
private static String[] rearrangeCities(String[] cities, int[] postalCode, int[] orderedPostCode) {
    final String[] orderedCities = new String[cities.length];
    for (int newPos = 0; newPos < orderedPostCode.length; newPos++) {
        final int curPostalCode = orderedPostCode[newPos];
        for (int oldPos = 0; oldPos < postalCode.length; oldPos++) {
            if (postalCode[oldPos] == curPostalCode) {
                orderedCities[newPos] = cities[oldPos];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return orderedCities;
}
```

Since your goal is to improve your knowledge of arrays in Java, I believe that these are good examples.

Answer (score 1):

When you search in the first array save the successful index and get that element of the other array.

```
    if(postalCode[i]==input)
        index=i;
```

and now you want `city[index]`

`index` should be declared outside of the searching for loop so that in can be accessed after the search(unless you won't need later access)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to improve your skills with arrays I guess this will help. nothing complex or efficient but this is enough.

```
 int[] postalcode = {9300,2000,1000,9200,9000,8500,9700,2300};
     String[] city = {"Aalst","Antwerpen","Brussel","Dendermonde","Gent","Kortrijk","Oudenaarde","Turnhout"};

     int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a postal code")); 

     for(int i = 0; i< postalcode.length;i++){
         if(postalcode[i] == code){
          System.out.println(city[i]); 
              //or do something with the value here
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two arrays *really* isn't the way to do this, but it appears what you have is the city at the same index in `city` as the corresponding code in `postalcode`

You would need to do a linear search through `postalcode` then pull the city:

```
String foundCity = null;
for (int i = 0; i < postalcode.length; i++)
{
    if (postalcode[i] == code)
    {
        foundCity = city[i]; 
        break;   
    }
}
```

If `foundCity` is not null, you found the zip and have the city.